# Windbg .IF failing with extender register

Tags: windbg

Why this is failing?

`r $t0=1;.if (@$t0 > 1‬) { .echo this is true } .else { .echo this is false }`

Syntax error at '‬) { .echo this is true } .else { .echo this is false }'

Answer (score 3):

You have copy/pasted your command from somewhere instead of typing it yourself. There's an invisible `\0` character after the `1`, causing the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks!!! I really appreciate, the error is not visible. I do not know how it has been introduced.